# Control Windows VM from Linux Host

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-scripting

I am looking for a tool that will allow me to monitor and control programs running inside a Windows VM from the Linux host machine. I realize that this is similar to what a rootkit would do, and I am completely happy to use some hacker software if it provides the necessary functionality (and if I can get it in source-code form).

If I can't find something, I'll have to write it using C. Probably an embedded HTTP server running on an odd port and doing some kind of XMLRPC thing.

Here is the basic functionality I need:

- Get list of running processes
- Kill a process.
- Start a process
- Read/write/create/delete files

I would like to:
 - Read contents of screen
 - Read all controls on screen.
 - Send arbitrary click to a Windows control.

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build Samba with WMI support from http://dev.zenoss.org/svn/trunk/inst/externallibs/wmi-1.2.9.tar.bz2. Not in the official Samba yet.

#### Get list of running processes

`wmic -UAdministrator //host "select * from Win32_Process"`

#### Kill a process

You need to run `wmic` on the Windows host  using `winexe` because Samba wmic only supports querying

`winexe -UAdministrator //host "wmic process where name=\"process.exe\" delete" # Kill process.exe`

`winexe -UAdministrator //host "wmic process where ProcessId=145 delete" # Kill pid 145`

#### Start a process

`winexe -UAdministrator //host process.exe`

#### Read/write/create/delete files

You probably want to use Samba read `man mount.cifs` and `man smbclient`

Comment: OMG that is amazing. I guess it uses the samba authentication system, so it's not technically a security hole.

Comment: Apparently wmic has been removed from SAMBA. See http://samba.2283325.n4.nabble.com/Current-status-of-WMI-support-in-Samba-4-td2480900.html. A recommended replacement is http://www.openwsman.org/.